# Tense/construction of verb following 'looked at'

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

For example, in a sentence like 'he looked at his enemy....(use the verb fall)', would one say falling or fall? I feel like if the sentence was watched, it would be fall, but now for this construction I am not sure. Is there a rule or something that dictates this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use only ***FALLING*** here.

There is a group of verbs connected with feeling, hearing and seeing can be used with -ing or with an infinitive without to:

feel

notice

see

hear

overhear

watch.
(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-and-imperatives/infinitives-with-and-without-to).

So after the verb ***LOOK*** we can use only -ing.